# Issues with nested scaffold's setters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, setter

I have 3 scaffolds that resources are nested as following: `mangas > chapters > scans`. I'm trying to create a website that allows visitors to read mangas chapters, but I'm getting some difficulties to set up the scan_controller's setter.

I have some constraints to follow: the manga scaffold uses FriendlyId, and both chapters and scans are shown to the URL via their chapter/scan number (an integer)

So, for the manga controller, i did the following:

```
  private
    def set_manga
      @manga = Manga.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I simply followed the manuel, no problem whatsoever.

For the chapter_controller, I did this

```
  private
    def set_chapter
      @manga = Manga.find_by(slug: params[:manga_id])
      @chapter = @manga.chapters.find_by(chapter_number: params[:id])
    end
```

This allows me to get all chapters that are linked to the manga I want, and only them. Plus, I get to pass the chapter_number as an id into the link.

And, lastly, I tried this for the scan_controller:

```
private
  def set_scan
    @manga = Manga.find_by(slug: params[:manga_id])
    @chapter = @manga.chapters.find_by(chapter_number: params[:id])
    @scan = @manga.chapters.scans.find(params[:id])
  end
```

However, at this point, I can't get a satisfying result. With this configuration, I get `undefined method 'pejis' for #<Chapter::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x0000000713d1a0>`. I tried to also set as follow:

```
 private

  def set_scan
    @chapter = Chapter.find_by(chapter_number: params[:id])
    @scan = @chapter.scans.find_by(scan_number: params[:id])
  end
```

But i get `undefined method 'pejis' for nil:NilClass`, which is weird because it doesn't return any error with predefined ids in the rails console.

As anyone an idea ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the last code snippet, can you confirm if `@chapter` isn't nil? Also, the second last snippet doesn't look fine. `@manga.chapters.scans` -- this should be changed to `@chapter.scans`.

Comment: for the last snippet, @chapter isn't nil as long as I set this : `@chapter = Chapter.find(params[:id])` instead of this `@chapter = Chapter.find_by(chapter_number: params[:id])`. When I do so, it tells me it can't find the chapter's id (that I didn't set anywhere so I guess it's logical)

Comment: `.find()` always finds by ID, and raises error if it couldn't find the required model in DB. On the other hand, `.find_by_*` methods don't raise any error, and return `nil` if the required model is not found in DB.

Comment: Oh ok, so technically it should work as long as it's set up correctly. But in this case, I don't get why I get nil, the record exists and the link that is proposed is correct

Comment: I ran some small tests, and I realized that the SQL request isn't good: Chapter Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `'chapters'.* FROM 'chapters' WHERE 'chapters'.'chapter_number' = 1 LIMIT 1`. It is supposed to find 4, not 1, because 1 is the `page_number` that it is supposed to get

Answer (score 0):

So, after re-reading again and again my code, I simply needed to do the following:

```
def set_peji
  @chapter = Chapter.find_by(chapter_number: params[:chapter_id])
  @peji = @chapter.pejis.find_by(scan_number: params[:id])
end
```

So I had to remove @manga since it's not concerned anymore, then to set the scan's chapter_id as being the chapter's number.